# Get / Set problems

Tags: c#, xna

Asteroids class

```
public Vector2 AsteroidPosition
{
    get { return asteroidPosition; }
    set { asteroidPosition = value; }
}
```

Set is called from Update method in Asteroids class

```
AsteroidPosition = new Vector2(spritePosition.X, spritePosition.Y);
```

Game class, collision detection method

```
Asteroids asteroid = new Asteroids();
Rectangle asteroidRectangle = new Rectangle(
    (int)asteroid.AsteroidPosition.X,
    (int)asteroid.AsteroidPosition.Y, 
    asteroidTexture.Width, 
    asteroidTexture.Height);
```

And this method is called in the Update method of Game class.

I add a break breakpoint at Set to check 'value' has a value and it does, so why does it keep return (0, 0)?

Comment: Exactly *what* is (0,0) - and when? Can you show where you give it a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asteroid instance is created on the first line of the collision detection method, and then used immediately on the second, so the values will be 0 unless you set them to something inside the constructor of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Ther's not Property set after Asteroids asteroid = new Asteroids(); . So it's get default value.